# Using python dictionary in for loop

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I am developing a project using django.
I am using python dictionary to display data in for loop. I have set a dynamic key as per my requirement in dictionary using following code.

```
abc = {}

for user in users
 abc[user] = "some dynamic data"

context = {
            'contributors ': abc
        }
return render(request, 'contacts.html', context)
```

I send above code to my template to display data for each user.

```
{% for contributor in contributors %}

    {% for contributor_mp in contributor %}
        {{  contributor_mp }}
    {% endfor %}


{% endfor %}
```

I could not even access my code in view as I got error when I tried to serialize my dictionary

```
error:'long' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I was using below to display my abc dictionary :

```
json_data = serializers.serialize("json", abc,use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
return HttpResponse(json_data)
```

So I used 
json_data = serializers.serialize("json", abc[123],use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
        return HttpResponse(json_data)

and got something like below (a validated json):

```
[{
    "fields": {
        "status": 0,
        "description": "Fresh & Healthy",
        "name": "Fresh & Healthy",
        "public": false,
        "custom_type": null,
        "user": "mpowner",
        "image_url": 
        "course_type": 1,
        "type": 1
    },
    "model": "mealplan",
    "pk": 140
}, {
    "fields": {
        "status": 0,
        "description": "evening snacks",
        "name": "evening snacks",
        "public": false,
        "custom_type": "health and taste",
        "user": "mpowner",
        "image_url": 
        "course_type": 1,
        "type": 1
    },
    "model": "mealplan",
    "pk": 155
}]
```

Now my problem is when I send this to my template I get an

```
error:'long' object is not iterable
```

As this is my first project in python and I am basically a php developer I am feeling really uncomfortable facing these kind of errors.Please help solving this and suggest some other way to use something like array ( a multi dimensional one) in python.

Answer (score 4):

To iterate a dict in django template you need to use `items`:

```
{% for contributor, dynamic_data in contributors.items %}
    {{ user }} {{ dynamic_data }}
{% endfor %}
```